# Dynamic Request body REST API Method using swagger

Tags: java, rest, swagger-ui

I have use case were I need to get requestBody based on selection of field.below is same code which I was able get the dynamic responseBody Based on selection ProtocolType.Is there is any way that swagger can read the RequestBody Dynamically.

### Controller.Java

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Protocol Account", tags = {"ProtocolAccount"}) 
@RequestMapping(value = "/protocolAccount/{protocolName}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE) 
@ResponseBody public ProtocolAccount getProtocol(@PathVariable String protocolName)
{ 
    return service.getProtocol(protocolName);
}
```

### Service.Java

```
public ProtocolAccount getProtocol(String protocolName){                    
    ProtocolAccount protocolAccount=new ProtocolAccount();
    Object object=ProtocolType.fromMap(protocolName);
    protocolAccount.setProtocol(object);
    return protocolAccount;
}
```

### POJOs

```
public class ProtocolAccount
{
    String Id;
    private Object protocolType
}

public class Protocol{
    private String port;
}

public class FTPProtocol extends Protocol{
    /*Some Fields*/
}

public class SFTPProtocol extends Protocol{
    /*Some Fields*/
}
```

### Enumeration

```
public enum ProtocolType
{
    SFTP("SFTP"), FTPS("FTPS"), AS2("AS2"), FTP("FTP");
    private final String value;
    private static final EnumMap<ProtocolType, 
        Object>map = new EnumMap<ProtocolType, Object>(ProtocolType.class);
    static{
        map.put(ProtocolType.SFTP, new SFTPProtocol());
        map.put(ProtocolType.FTP, new FTPProtocol());
        map.put(ProtocolType.FTPS,new FTPSProtocol());
    }

    ProtocolType(String v){
        value=v;
    }

    public static ProtocolType fromValue(String val){
        return EnumSet.allOf(ProtocolType.class)
            .stream().filter(e->e.value.equals(val))
            .findFirst().orElseThrow(()->new IllegalArgumentException(val));
    }

    public String value(){
        return value;
    }

    public static  Object fromMap(String value)
    {
        return map.get(ProtocolType.fromValue(value));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great question - in general, how well does Swagger work with [domain agnostic REST APIs](https://books.google.com/books?id=Kez1TGNIBPIC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=domain+agnostic+hypermedia&source=bl&ots=DDHa-ji3je&sig=0PSDNCmIuLu1p6oIJTVimMOChMs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGzMSboqPaAhXDZd8KHcnVCf8Q6AEILjAA#v=onepage&q=domain%20agnostic%20hypermedia&f=false)